# Landypy not understanding how to connect

Tags: c#

I am trying to query AD using this project,

https://landpyactivedirectory.codeplex.com/documentation

```
using Landpy.ActiveDirectory.Core;
using Landpy.ActiveDirectory.Entity.Object;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    public class aLandypyTest
    {
        protected IADOperator ADOperator { get; set; }

        public void CallAD1000Times()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                using (var userObject = UserObject.FindOneByCN(this.ADOperator, 'pangxiaoliang'))
                {
                     // do something.
                }
```

But I am getting this error,

> Error 2   The best overloaded method match for
>   'Landpy.ActiveDirectory.Entity.Object.UserObject.FindOneByCN(Landpy.ActiveDirectory.Core.IADOperator,
>   string)' has some invalid
>   arguments D:\BackUp\TestConsoleApp\TestConsoleApp\TestConsoleApp\aLandypyTest.cs  20  41  TestConsoleApp

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 'pangxiaoliang' to "pangxiaoliang". Typo. The compiler wants a string for second parameter, but if You wrap it with **'** it's not a string. You have to wrap it in **"**.